# How to occupy a 10 by 10 block with 2 * 3 blocks that doesn't let others to push another 2 * 3

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to find out the minimum number of 2 * 3 blocks that I can fill in 100 pixels that don't allow any other 2 * 3 blocks to fill in like the below picture.

```
2 * 3 in 10 * 10 = 6
```

[image]

or another example:

```
2 * 1 in 5 * 7 = 14
```

[image]

I've searched a lot but I've not been successful so far. I do not want any code but I want the algorithm name or any advice to find my way.

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do the rectangles all have to be facing the same orientation?

Comment: Ok, can I rotate the rectangles by some arbitrary amount (say, 45˚), or must they only be rotated by multiples of 90˚?

Comment: Sorry my bad, It does matter

Comment: So if I have to pack 2x3 rectangles, I can do 2x3 or 3x2, correct? Also, do you have to output the final configuration, or only find the *maximum amount*?

Comment: Only finding the maximum amount is enogh

Comment: Alright, let me try to help you out here.

Comment: Where's your attempt at all? At the minimum, brute force with backtracking will always work, even if inefficient. Do at least make it work with brute force first.

Comment: Yes, what is the expected time complexity?

Comment: 1 second and 256 MB

Comment: What are the bounds on N? This looks like an online judge question - do you have the link?

Comment: it's in Persian

Comment: OK, can you tell me how big the rectangles can be?

Comment: it's changeable, and I get it in an array of integers like 10 10 2 3 which means 10 * 10 and 2 * 3

Comment: I don't mind Persian, so what's the link?

Comment: And please add information about rotations, limits, etc to the *question*, not just in comments. Right now I can't even tell whether rotations are allowed, at least one comment seems to have been deleted already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments I understood, that we can't rotate rectangles. So then we use the following approach:

Imagine, you want to solve the same problem, but only for the line, where rect size is 1xRectW in 1xGridW grid.

I will use "X" for rect cell, "0" for empty cell.
Example has 1x3 rect and 1x10 grid.

From the left side I can leave empty (RectW - 1) cells at max:

```
00XXX00000
```

Then I can leave empty (RectW - 1) cells at max from the previous’s rect right side:

```
00XXX00XXX
```

Now I let's add another dimension. Let's say we have 2 rows. I can keep using the same logic here, but instead of copying rectangle, I will copy the whole first row:

```
00XXX00XXX
00XXX00XXX
```

Now we want to do the same for 2x4 rectangle in 10x11 grid. Here we got rectangle of height 2, so we will use 2 rows for the first step:

```
000XXXXXXXX
000XXXXXXXX
```

And extend it for rows:

```
00000000000
000XXXXXXXX
000XXXXXXXX
00000000000
000XXXXXXXX
000XXXXXXXX
00000000000
000XXXXXXXX
000XXXXXXXX
00000000000
```

As you can notice, we add extra (RectH - 1) on the top.

If you will pay attention, you will see, that actually we are just performing division with rounding.

So in python we can express this idea with mathematical abstraction like this:

```
def solver(rectH, rectW, gridH, gridW) -> int:
    w = round(gridW / (rectW * 2 - 1))
    h = round(gridH / (rectH * 2 - 1))
    return w * h
```

Results:

```
>>> solver(2, 3, 10, 10)
6
>>> solver(2, 1, 5, 7)
14
```